# Zynq7 / Zedboard: Xil_in32 alters data when reading from DRAM

Tags: fpga, xilinx, zynq

I have a Zedboard with the following setup in the PL (FPGA):

Custom AXI (full) master -> Interconnect -> Zynq_PS (HP0 slave port)

- The custom AXI master produces data (simple counter, written to DRAM, starting at 0x00000000).
- The data are written to DRAM (according to XMD console -> mrd 0x00000000 10)
- When the PS wants to read the data (main.c -> calls "Xil_in32(0x00000000)") the **data is altered** !!!

Question:
Is calling the function Xil_in32 (for reading data from DRAM) altering the data itself in certain situations ? (when and why ?)

The data are not altered unless Xil_in32 is called. This is proved by reading data from XMD console before calling Xil_in32 from main.c

C-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "platform.h"
#include <unistd.h>

#include "xparameters.h"
#include "xil_io.h"
#include "xstatus.h"
#include "xscugic.h"
#include "xil_exception.h"

#include "ps7_init.h"

#define PARAM_BASE_ADDRESS               0x00000000

int main()
{
    // initialization
    init_platform();
    //ps7_init();
    ps7_post_config();

    // variables
    u32 offset;
    u32 param;
    int i = 0;
    xil_printf(" PL WRITING & PS READING DRAM MEMORY TEST ");

    // loop
    while ( 1 ) {

        getchar();

        offset = 0X00000000;
        for (i = 0; i < 50 ; i++){
            offset = offset + 4;
            param = Xil_In32(PARAM_BASE_ADDRESS + offset);
            xil_printf("mem_read %d : %x \n\r",i , param);
        }
    }

    cleanup_platform();
    return 0;
}
```

XMD reading data:
This shows where I have stopped reading the memory, the counter then continues:

```
  C8:   7252E9D5
  CC:   D7387D6F
  D0:   1E998873
  D4:   5DD8305F
  D8:   C4FEC147
  DC:   347EBE2F <------ last memory read by Xil_in32
  E0:   0000003F <------ counter
  E4:   00000040 
  E8:   00000041
  EC:   00000042
  F0:   00000043
  F4:   00000044
  F8:   00000045
  FC:   00000046
 100:   00000047
 104:   00000048
 108:   00000049
 10C:   0000004A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION 1)

disabling caches, by running either cleanup_platform(), or the disable_caches(); (defined in platform.c) solves the problem of altering data.

QUESTIONS:

2) What disabling caches mean for practical application ? Everything is directly taken/written to DRAM ?

3) Is there any workaround, so that only part of memory is read/written directly ? (Not using caches seems terribly inefficient when the ARM is calculating something, therefore I would like to avoid it)

SOLUTION 2)

flush the cache before reading the data from DRAM by calling Xil_DCacheFlushRange(PARAM_BASE_ADDRESS, 4*1); (defined in xil_cache.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "platform.h"
#include <unistd.h>

#include "xparameters.h"
#include "xil_io.h"
#include "xstatus.h"
#include "xscugic.h"
#include "xil_exception.h"

#include "ps7_init.h"
#include "xil_cache.h"

#define PARAM_BASE_ADDRESS               0x00000000

int main()
{
    // initialization
    init_platform();
    //ps7_init();
    ps7_post_config();
    // cleanup_platform();                                  // DISABLING CACHES


    // variables
    u32 offset;
    u32 param;
    int i = 0;
    xil_printf(" PL WRITING & PS READING DRAM MEMORY TEST ");

    // loop
    while ( 1 ) {

        getchar();

        Xil_DCacheFlushRange(PARAM_BASE_ADDRESS, 4*1);      // CACHE FLUSHING
        offset = 0X00000000;
        for (i = 0; i < 50 ; i++){                          // LOOP FOR READING DATA
            param = Xil_In32(PARAM_BASE_ADDRESS + offset);
            xil_printf("mem_read %d : %x \n\r",i , param);
            offset = offset + 4;
        }
    }

    cleanup_platform();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can it be that there is a cache size somewhere in the Vivado design that is configured to use the DRAM block at address `0x00`, up to `0xe0`. But it seems like a ridiculous cache size... Unless there is not enough data to fill it up and alter your data?

Comment: The AXI ACP port gives cache coherent access to DDR